# No vue component on fresh installed laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have install a fresh laravel on my machine. while reading tutorials about laravel vue, they already have a vue component named **"ExampleComponent.vue"** on their machine under

**resources/assets/components**

but when i look on resources folder i dont have the components folder but when i see the package.json there are vue installed on it as well as vue-router.

I do also have ExampleComponent.vue but in the vendor folder. Am i installed laravel or vue on a wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Laravel 6, JavaScript & CSS scaffolding was moved to a separate package.
https://laravel.com/docs/master/frontend

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev
```

See the linked resource for provisioning specific items.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. i already seen my vue components.

Answer (score 1):

**Laravel < v6**

You should install npm packages

```
npm install
```

read Laravel Document: [JavaScript & CSS Scaffolding](https://laravel.com/docs/master/frontend)

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands step by step in your Dev folder using your Terminal:

1. composer require laravel/ui
2. Then here you have to choose which components to install,

   php artisan ui bootstrap
   or
   php artisan ui vue
   or
   php artisan ui react
3. npm install
4. This is the final thing to Run, and the missing Components Folder will be installed.

   npm run dev

   or
5. Follow this link everything is explained fully.
   https://laravel.com/docs/master/frontend

Answer (score 0):

run these two commands

```
php artisan ui bootstrap
```

**and then**

```
php artisan ui vue
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend